# errors in validating GTFS files files are not found

Tags: gtfs

every time i enter my zip folder in the validation tool , i receive this error 
for all 6 required files , although they are included

The file named dina/agency.txt was not expected.
This may be a misspelled file name or the file may be included in a subdirectory. Please check spellings and make sure that there are no subdirectories within the feed
in dina/agency.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the files in the GTFS need to be in the root directory.

It seems that you have them in a directory called Dina. Take them out of the directory (e.g. create the zip file from the same directory as the files) and you shouldn't see the error.